# WPF animate Panel.ZIndex

Tags: wpf, vb.net, animation, z-index

I'm having problem with animating the zindex. Here is my code

```
<ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="card1" Duration="00:00:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)" From="99" To="98"/>
```

Or the DoubleAnimation won't work either, anyone can give me a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `SplineInt32KeyFrame` with `Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames`. So something like this:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
    <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="card1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)">
        <SplineInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.00" Value="99"/>
        <SplineInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.02" Value="98"/>
    </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

I believe `ThicknessAnimation` and `DoubleAnimation` weren't working as [`ZIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) wants an `Int32`.

Comment: Or just change `ThicknessAnimation` to `Int32Animation`.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, thanks Darren and Novitchi.
Here is the simpler working code.

```
<Int32Animation Storyboard.TargetName="card1" Duration="00:00:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)" From="99" To="98"/>
```